# Hibernate generating query for Oracle which causes ORA-02014

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

My project uses Hibernate version 4.0.1.Final with JPA 2.0. I needed to change one HQL - add order, looked simple enough except its now ending with SQL sytax error.

I have defined this HQL named query:

> SELECT s FROM Entity s WHERE s.status = :status **ORDER BY s.priority,
>   s.startDate**

-> **Bold** is part which I want to add.

Now since this named query is executed with lock - **LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE** its creating for update select for Oracle:

```
select *
  from (select entity.field 

  ...more fields...

          from DB_TABLE entity
         where (entity.STATUS = ?)
         order by entity.PRIORITY, entity.DISTRIB_START_DATE)
 where rownum <= ?
   for update
```

And this query ending with

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02014 cannot select FOR UPDATE from view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY

Without the order part its working fine.

Is there any way how to get over this? I just need select those records in order. Also cannot order them in application cause its selecting only part of table.

I tried to update Hibernate to 4.2.21.Final but the result is the same. Hibernate 4.3+ requires JPA2.1 which I do not use.

Maybe is this Hibernate bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not a Hibernate bug, it is the way how you have to do ordering combined with `rownum` in Oracle. See [this article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html) for more details.

Basically, that means that you cannot combine ordering, `rownum` and `select for update` in the same query in Oracle.

You'll have to break it to more queries and the exact approach depends on what your specific requirements are. For example:

1) Select ids of the entities with **paging** and **ordering**:

```
SELECT s.id FROM Entity s WHERE s.status = :status ORDER BY s.priority, s.startDate
```

2) Select the entities with **locking** using the obtained ids:

```
SELECT s FROM Entity s WHERE s.id in :ids AND s.status = :status
```

3) If the count of the selected entities is less than the count of ids, then conditions have changed in the meantime (status has changed), continue the processing with the locked instances or rollback and retry the entire transaction.